# How do I know the working directory of my apache web service?

Tags: java, python, apache, ubuntu

I have a python client (ubuntu) which calls the following web service:
    http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8774/v2/8d118e773c6a44c88f64960c1177ede6/getNodes'

Both client and server are located on the same machine.
How can I find to which working directory this web service (which my client is calling) is pointing to?

(I don't know the source of the web Service. All I know that it is running on the same box and its url. How do I get to the source with these two clues?)

Answer (score 0):

Since it is Ubuntu, you can find all the configured Apache hosts in `/etc/apache/sites-enabled`. One of the files in there will be your web service, and will specify its directory.